# Why is this.$route.params null?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to pass data to another page and I use the following code:

```
  this.$router.push({ path: '/guard/foreigner-list', params: data});
```

Then I expect item is equal to data, but item is null

```
let item = this.$route.params;
```

Answer (score 1):

Start from [vue-router@4.1.4](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22) (2022-08-22) passing object through `params` is no longer a viable option, since it is consider as anti-pattern.

However,

> there are multiple alternatives to this anti-pattern:
>
> - Putting the data in a store like pinia: this is relevant if the data is used across multiple pages
> - Move the data to an actual param by defining it on the route's path or pass it as query params: this is relevant if you have small pieces of data that can fit in the URL and should be preserved when reloading the page
> - Pass the data as state to save it to the History API state: ...
> - Pass it as a new property to to.meta during navigation guards: ...

Answer (score 0):

You did not posted the entire code that is related to the process of changing route. But according to [Vue Router documentation](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html):

> `params` are ignored if a `path` is provided, which is not the case for query, as shown in the examples. Instead, you need to provide the `name` of the route or manually specify the whole `path` with any parameter

So if you have defined a route called user in your `router.js` file like below:

```js
import User from "../views/User"

const routes = [
  { 
    path: '/user/:id',
    name: 'User',
    component: User
  }
]
```

Then you can [navigate programmatically](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) from `Home.vue` to `User.vue` with the codes below:

> Home.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <button @click="navigFunc">click to navigate</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  methods: {
    navigFunc: function () {
      const id = '123';
      // using "name" not "path"
      this.$router.push({ name: 'User', params: { id } });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

> User.vue:

```html
<template>
<section>
  <h1>User page</h1>
</section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "User",
  mounted() {
  /* access the params like this */
    console.log(this.$route.params)
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Notice that the variable I defined (`id`), is the same as the `params` that was defined in router.js (path: '/user/:`id`').